# Adjectif ou complément du nom: "Connaissances de la culture française" contre "Connaissances culturelles de France"

Tags: sens, adjectifs, compléments

Je voudrais poser une question sur la signification de ces deux options ci-dessous.  Il semble qu'il y ait de fortes nuances.

> "Connaissances de la culture française" et "Connaissances culturelles de France."

Comment: Elles sont antinomiques, la première évoque La culture française dans son essence, tout ce qui peut définir sa spécificité ; la seconde évoque les différentes cultures que la France [re]connaît en dehors de la sienne.

Comment: Merci beaucoup. Pourriez-vous doner quelques exemples, s'il vous plaît.

Comment: Pour la culture française : https://books.google.fr/books?id=m1GvDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT108&dq=%22culture+fran%C3%A7aise%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYueWm38LpAhWP2BQKHTbMA6IQ6AEIMjAB#v=onepage&q=%22culture%20fran%C3%A7aise%22&f=false

Comment: Les Basques, Bretons, Corses, Kanaks, habitants de Wallis-et-Futuna … ont chacun leur propre culture identifiable par leur langue, leurs coutumes et autres arts de vivre (adapté à l’Amazonie par exemple en Guyane), ils sont  Français avec une double culture. En France la culture française cohabite en paix avec les cultures autochtones.

Comment: Merci beaucoup.

Answer (score 4):

La première expression, *connaissances de la culture française*, est curieuse par l'utilisation du pluriel.

Au singulier, *connaissance de la culture française* est tout à fait idiomatique, *la connaissance*, c'est le fait de connaître, mais au pluriel, il est difficile de comprendre le sens souhaité car il n'y a pas plusieurs connaissances d'une culture donnée, on la connait ou on ne la connait pas. *Connaissances* peut aussi vouloir dire les personnes que l'on connait, mais ce sens n'est pas possible ici, la culture française n'ayant pas de connaissances.

La deuxième expression, *connaissances culturelles de France*, manque de contexte pour être intelligible.

Comment: Merci beaucoup.

Answer (score 0):

**Unfortunately none of the sentences is correct. The second sentence is incomplete but it is especially the association of words that makes it incorrect. The first sentence is wrong in terms of common sense (grammar and semantics).**

La seconde phrase est vraiment incompréhensible.

1. L'adjectif est en effet relatif à la connaissance. ⮞ <s>connaissances culturelles</s>
2. L'adjectif évoque également la dimension géographique (nation, civilisation...).

> #### [LE TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/culturelle)
>
> A. Qui est relatif à la culture *en tant que acquisition et possession* par l'esprit *des connaissances* qui l'enrichissent.
>
> B. Qui est relatif à un mode de culture traditionnel *dans une société donnée* consistant en un ensemble de connaissances et de valeurs abstraites acquises méthodiquement.

3. Qui est abstrait et non lié à la zone géographique. ⮞ <s>culturelles de France</s>

Le sens de la première phrase serait en principe équivalent à *connaître la culture française*. La culture renvoie à quelque chose de général, de variable ou bien non déterminé, donc l'article est obligatoirement l'article indéfini singulier.

Comment: Merci beaucoup.

Comment: Pourquoi le vote négatif à cette réponse ?

Answer (score 0):

Just from curiosity I posted some time ago a similar question in another forum.
The feedback received is that

> La première doit bien signifier que la personne a une connaissance (plutôt au singulier) de la culture française et la seconde ne signifie rien.

https://www.question-orthographe.fr/question/connaissances-de-la-culture-francaise-versus-connaissances-culturelles-de-france/